# Formatting a number in gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, formatting

i have a gridview that shows some indicators.one of the numbers is a computed percentage it looks like this "33.33333333333333333333333333333333333333" i tried to set the DataFormatString property of the column to several different formats such as "{0:P}" ,"{0:D}" and "{0:##.##}" but nothing worked for me to show it like that "33.34". Any ideas?

Comment: Surely, you'd want it to show "33.33", and not "33.34"?

Comment: 33.34 would be the result of rounding that number

Answer (score 2):

What happens if you use "{0:F2}"?

Answer (score 1):

Try entering just the format string without braces and the index,eg. P, D or ##.### .  The braces and index are used by String.Format, where there are more than one format parameters. ToString methods (e.g. int.ToString) and control format parameters use only the format string without braces

Comment: Without the curly braces..it shows it as text,if i set the property DataFormatString="P" it just shows all the values in that columns as "P"